# Uploading a file to different Unix boxes in one go

Tags: unix, ssh, winscp

I have to upload few files from my Windows machine to different Unix boxes using WinSCP software at regular intervals.

The pain is that let's say I have 4 different Unix boxes so in WinSCP I have to open that 4 different Unix boxes individually, to upload the files.

Please advise is there any software through which I can graphically open the four Unix boxes simultaneously and upload the files to the same location?

Comment: consider eschewing the GUI when doing batch operations. I'd use pssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a batch file that connects and uploads a file to all hosts sequentially.

With [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) the batch file can be like:

```
@echo off
set UPLOAD=winscp.com /command "open %%1%%" "put ""%1""" "exit" /parameter
%UPLOAD% ftp://martin:password@server1.example.com/home/martin/
%UPLOAD% sftp://user:password@server2.example.com/home/user/
```

Now you can call the batch file (say `multiupload.bat`) with a file path as an argument:

```
multiupload.bat c:\path\upload.txt
```

You can even drop/link the batch file in Explorer's "SendTo" folder to easily use it from the Explorer's "Send To" menu:

[image: Send To Multipload]

Some references:

- [Guide to automating file upload to SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation)
- A practical [example for upload to a single host](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_single_file)
- Making the script [take name of file to upload as parameter](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#syntax) to easily reuse it.
- Example for creating [parametrized script to upload files](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_multiple_servers):
- [Creating entry in Explorer's "Send To" menu](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#using).

Answer (score 1):

Open 4 tabs in WinSCP?

Or

Write a script to scp them from 1 on the Unix machines to the rest of the Unix machines?

Adding more info:

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/transfer_queue
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_tabs

Either of the two should help